# Why after populate array of values is becoming null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to populate answers(comments) on my post . But on populating it becomes null while before that it stores fine of storing Id's of answer.

## My schema of post

```
var doubtsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    content : String,
    tags : String,
    created : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now},
    author : {
        id : {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref : "User"},
        username : String},
    answers : [{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Answers"}]});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Doubts",doubtsSchema);
```

## My schema of answer

```
var answersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content : String,
    created : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now},
    author : {
        id : {
            type : mongoose .Schema .Types . ObjectId, 
            ref  : "User"},
        username : String},
    likes_count : Number});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Answers",answersSchema);
```

## Populate is not working

```
Doubts.findById(req.params.id).populate('answers').exec(function(err,foundDoubt) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("here");
        console.log(foundDoubt);
        res.render("doubts/show",{doubt : foundDoubt});
    }
});
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children `There are two perspectives here. First, you may want the author know which stories are theirs. Usually, your schema should resolve one-to-many relationships by having a parent pointer in the 'many' side. But, if you have a good reason to want an array of child pointers, you can push() documents onto the array as shown below.`

Comment: @NikitaUmnov Thankyou for your help. But can you please tell me what should i do now ,because it's not working. Should i write brute code to populate?

Comment: If in doubt you can edit your question to include a document from your `doubts` collection and the `answers` documents you believe to be related which are showing up as `null`. What you will likely find though is that the `_id` values in the `answers` collection do not match up with those in the `answers` array of the parent document, since your code has likely managed to insert different values or possibly never saved the `answers` documents at all. So it's the "creation code" and not the "population code" this is the problem here. Show that code if you do not spot the problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn  when i checked out the database, the "answers" of doubtSchema is containing the ObjectId of answers . The only problem arises when I'm using the "populate('answers')" . It then nullifies the answers of doubtSchema.

Comment: What you were actually asked to do is "show the documents". If you think the data is correct, then by all means "show it". Then someone can actually use that same data to either reproduce the problem, or not. With the latter case really only being able to show an example which may do something differently, than other code you have not included in the question. But you really need to ***show the data"** first.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example, it works

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comments"}]
});

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: ""
});

const Users = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
const Comments = mongoose.model("Comments", CommentSchema);

// Adding data
Promise.all([
    new Comments({content: "test 1"}).save(),
    new Comments({content: "test 2"}).save(),
    new Comments({content: "test 3"}).save()
]).then(result => {
    result = result.map(r => r._id);
    new Users({name: "test", comments: result}).save().then(user => {
        // Getting with populate
        Users.findById(user._id).populate("comments").then(console.log);
    })
}).catch(console.error);
```

In console:

```
{ comments:
   [ { _id: 5c979d9dedc0b1db90fe81dd, content: 'test 1', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5c979d9dedc0b1db90fe81de, content: 'test 2', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5c979d9dedc0b1db90fe81df, content: 'test 3', __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5c979d9dedc0b1db90fe81e0,
  name: 'test',
  __v: 0 }
```

Maybe it will help to find the error